# Build D.E. that $\Psi_{\gamma,\kappa,\rho}(t)=e^{{\gamma}it}e^{(\kappa A+\rho A^*)}$ solves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, heat-equation, wave-equation

Consider $$\Psi_{\gamma,\kappa,\rho}(t)=e^{{\gamma}it}e^{(\kappa A+\rho A^*)}$$

for real parameters $\gamma,\kappa,\rho>0$, real variable $t\in(0,1)$ and $A=\frac{1}{\log(t)},$ $A^*=\frac{1}{\log(1-t)}.$

> How do I build the differential equation that $\Psi$ solves?

Consider $h_{\kappa}(t)=e^{\kappa A}$ and $j_{\rho}(t)=e^{\rho A^*}$ and $g_{\gamma}(t)=e^{\gamma it}.$

Then we have a solution of the form: $\Psi(t)=h(t)j(t)g(t).$

We know that $h_{\kappa}(t)$ satisfies the linear parabolic  PDE:

$$\kappa \frac{\partial ^2\Psi(\kappa,t)}{\partial {\kappa}^2}=-t \frac{\partial \Psi(\kappa,t)}{\partial t}  $$

and $j$ likewise satisfies a linear parabolic PDE:

> Now the question is: Does multiplying the solutions together also solve a PDE?

[image]

Here's an image of $\Psi$ for $\gamma=7,~ \kappa=0.3,~ \rho=0.9.$

Comment: A wave equation requires time and space (a wave moves in time and space). So what is it that you mean there? Your functions satisfies a quite simple ordinary differential equation. Which I wouldn't call a wave equation though.

Comment: @Icv yeah that's the problem I'm having. I have to add another variable I think.

Comment: I need for $\Psi$ to satisfy the wave equation but I'm having a bit of difficulty building up to that.

Comment: My thought is that I need to introduce a phase